# Multiplying two bytes representing a short by 1.5

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, z80

I was looking at some assembly code and came across the following (which I've converted for ease of the reader).  All registers are 8 bits, and pointers are 16 bits.  So `(q)` loads 8 bits.

`(q+1) = (q+1) = rr(q+1)` where `(q)` dereferences `q` and `rr(q)` is rotate right
`(q) = (q) + (q)/2 + bit((q+1), 0)` where `bit((q+1), 0)` is getting the 0th bit of `(q+1)`

This really confused me, because what the above code does is multiply a 16 bit value by 1.5, regardless of its endianness (i.e. however you interpret q be it little endian or big endian, its value is multiplied by 1.5 in its respective endian).

I'm confused about how they're going about multiplying a 16 bit value by 1.5 using two 8 bit values.  Whats going on here? Specifically, what is the purpose of adding the 0th bit of `(q+1) to (q)` and the purpose of rotating `(q+1)` to the right?

Here is the assembly code:

```
ld a, (q)
ld b, a
ld a, (q+1)
ld c, a
srl b
rr c
add c
ld (q+1), a
ld a, (q)
adc b
ld (q), a
ret
```

Comment: I would help to know what CPU this is supposed to be for, but it looks like the SRL/RR instructions perform a 16-bit shift right (ie. divide by 2), while the ADD/ADC instructions perform a 16-bit add. So it calculates Q = Q / 2 + Q, where Q is the 16-bit big endian value stored at `(q)` and `(q+1)`.

Comment: Sorry for not including that, but its the gameboy CPU, I think Z80 assembly so srl,rr etc operate on 8 bits only

Comment: In combination SRL and RR are working together to perform a 16-bit shift. Similarly ADD and ADC work together to perform a 16-bit add.

Comment: Interesting that this is obviously a big-endian operation done on a Z80, 8080 or 8085 which use little-endian for hardware 16-bit operations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't take the time to read through all of the assembly code in detail, but I strongly suspect @Ross Ridge is right.

This trick is called Horner's method. It's especially common in smaller embedded MCUs without multipliers, but can be used for general speed optimization. See

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa329/slaa329.pdf